# Add slider functionality to dynamically created objects

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using the .clone() method to create copies of a collection of nested elements every time a user presses a button.

However, within each group of elements I need a slider that will attach to the slide functionality but which should only change the value of items within that particular collection.

How do I create a new instance of the slider for each collection created.

The below code works for a hard-coded slider with the id of "value-slider" but I need the below code to work for each instance of the cloned slider.

Thanks for your help

```
$(function() {
    $( "#value-slider" ).slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",             
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        step: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            $( ".amount" ).val( "£" + ui.value + " - £" + (ui.value + 100) );
            $( ".price" ).text( "£" + (ui.value / 19).toFixed(2)  );
            $( ".i-price" ).text( "£" + (ui.value / 19).toFixed(2)  );
        }
    });
    $( ".amount" ).val( "£" + $( ".value-slider" ).slider( "value" ) + " - £" + ($( ".value-slider" ).slider( "value" ) + 100) );
});
```

The markup of the element that is to be cloned is below (notice how the slide is just a descendant of the cloned element :

```
<div id="template" class="basket-item group hide" style="display:none;">
  <div class="basket-item-icon"><img /></div>
  <div class="basket-item-details"> </div>
  <div class="basket-item-slider">
    <div style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; float:left;color:#F6931F; ">£0</div>
    <div class="value-slider" style="width:140px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"></div>
    <div style="width:30px; font-weight:bold; float:left;color:#F6931F; ">£1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="basket-item-value">Value:
    <input type="text" class="amount" style="margin:2px 0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; width:90px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="basket-item-cover-price">Our Price:<br />
    <span class="i-price" style="font-size:24px; color:#F6931F;">£x.xx</span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a function that accepts an element and attaches the slider:

```
function addSlider(element) {
   var slider = $('.value-slider', element).slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",             
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        step: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount", element).val( "£" + ui.value + " - £" + (ui.value + 100) );
            var price = "£" + (ui.value / 19).toFixed(2);
            $( ".price", element).text(price);
            $( ".i-price", element).text(price);
        }
    });
    $( ".amount", element).val( "£" + slider.slider( "value" ) + " - £" + (slider.slider( "value" ) + 100) );
}
```

<del>*(Assuming `.amount`, `.price` etc are descendants of the element you add the slider to. You might have to adjust this. It is impossible to provide a totally correct solution without knowing the HTML structure)*</del>

Then, when you clone the element, you just pass the clone to the function:

```
var clone = $('some selector').clone();
addSlider(clone.get(0));
```

---

Alternatively you can try cloning the element with `clone(true)` which will also clone event handlers and data associated with the element.

Comment: Hi Felix, I want to add the slider to a descendant of the element that is being cloned. Your example turns the whole element into a slider. The markup of the element to be cloned is shown in shown in my edited question:

Comment: @FloatLeft: Ok, see my updated answer. I changed the function a bit.